# Search a limited span of a string with re.search

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to extract a substring containing numerical digits from a general string of the form:

```
filename = 'AB-CDE-FG-HI-10.000 GHz#1 JK LM.dat'
```

I need to extract just the '10.000'.

I have tried using

```
m = re.search(r"-(.*) GHz",filename)
```

But this returns

```
In[67]: m.group(1)
Out[67]: 'CDE-FG-HI-10.000'
```

That is, it returns everything between the *first* hyphen and the 'GHz' substring. Is there a way to limit the range over which the search is performed? I know that the digits before 'GHz' will only be 5 or 6 characters in length.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for `GHz`. Use something like

```
(\d+\.\d+)(?= GHz)
```

This will make a capture group for *only* the number before the `GHz`, while excluding the actual occurrence of `GHz`.

***Note***: The space before the `GHz` in the pattern is intentional, as there will always be a space before the `GHz` after the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.search(r"(\d+\.\d+) GHz", filename).group(1)` since `\d+\.\d+` will grab a set of integers followed by a decimal point followed by another set of integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookahead :

Using search method:

```
import re
pattern=r'\d.+(?=GHz)'

filename = 'AB-CDE-FG-HI-10.000 GHz#1 JK LM.dat'

search=re.search(pattern,filename,re.M)

print(search.group())
```

Using findall:

```
import re
pattern=r'\d.+(?=GHz)'

filename = 'AB-CDE-FG-HI-10.000 GHz#1 JK LM.dat'

search=re.findall(pattern,filename,re.M)

print(" ".join(list(search)))
```

Output:

```
10.000
```